# Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided even while existing multipartResolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I try to implement loading a photo and String object. Here is a declaration of my method.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<UserWithPhoto> update(@RequestHeader(value="Access-key") String accessKey,
                                         @RequestHeader(value="Secret-key") String secretKey,
                                         @RequestPart("user") String string,
                                         @RequestPart("photo") MultipartFile file) throws Exception
```

And this is my multi part resolver

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
 </beans:bean>
```

And I havn't idea why I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always wrap multipart files in a POJO with other properties needed:

```
public class FileUpload {

   private Long id;
   private MultipartFile file;

   // getters and setters
}
```

In my view:

```
<spring:url value="/myEndpoint" var="url_upload"/>
<form:form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" commandName="fileUpload" action="${url_upload}" >

    <form:hidden path="id" />
    <input type="file" name="file" id="inputFile"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form:form>
```

And in the endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myEndpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFile(@ModelAttribute("fileUpload") FileUpload dto, Model uiModel) {
    // Process file
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this block code to your config:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/index" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

and load your config on web.xml

Comment: to become an answer, this misses at least some line :)